# Getting "Illegal Seek" error after calling accept()

Tags: sockets, errno

Well.. it's pretty much that, I seem to be getting a "Illegal Seek" error when checking my errno variable. The problem is that I have no idea of what that can mean.

I know sockets are treated like files in unix, but I can't see how can this be related to sockets. What I'm doing exactly is:

```
int sck = ::accept(m_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_address, (socklen_t*)&address_len);
```

Then I get **sck = -1** and **errno = ESPIPE**

And the weird thing is that it happens randomly. I mean, sometimes the code works fine, and sometimes it just thows an exception. I'm working with threads so that's understandable. But I just would like to know what kind of behaviour makes the accept() call to set errno as ESPIPE so I could check the paramethers for instance.

Thanks
Nelson R. Pérez

Comment: Have you tried running `strace` on your executable?  You could see more definitively how `accept` is failing.  The `man` page doesn't include anything about `ESPIPE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable cause is that the `m_socket` variable is being corrupted. Use `strace` as @Aidan suggests to see what value is being passed to `accept(2)`, or attach a debugger to the process and set a *watchpoint* on that memory location.

Comment: Not necessarily the variable - it might be that the file descriptor has been closed and another file was opened and assigned the same number (since they're always assigned sequentially).

Comment: Hmm, yes, possible. That would sorta qualify as corruption though :) and a watchpoint would show where it's being changed.