# Data transfer over TCP-IPv6 connection

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming, client-server, ipv6

I am working on a client-server application in C and on Linux platform. What I am trying to achieve is to change the socket id over a TCP connection on both client and server without data loss where in the client sends the data from a file to the server in the main thread. The application is multithreaded where the other threads change the socket id based on some global flags set.

Problem: The application has two TCP socket connections established, over both IPv4 and IPv6 paths. I am transferring a file over the TCP-IPv4 connection first in the main thread. The other thread is checking on some global flags and has access to/share the socket IDs created for each protocol in the main thread. The send and recv use a pointer variable in its call to point to the socket ID to be used for the data transfer. The data is transferred initially over TCP-Ipv4. Once the global flags are set and few other checks are made the other thread changes the socket ID used in send call to point to IPv6 socket. This thread also takes care of communicating the change between the two hosts.I am getting all the data over IPv4 sent completely before switching. Also I am getting data sent over Ipv6 after the socket ID is just switched. But down the transfer there is loss of data over IPv6 connection.(I am using a pointer variable in send function on server side `send(*p_dataSocket.socket_id,sentence,p_size,0);` to change the pointer to IPv6 socket ID on the fly)

The error after recv and send call on both side respectively is says `ESPIPE:Illegal seek`, but this error exists even before switching. So I am pretty much sure this is nothing to do with the data loss

I am using `pselect()` to check for the available data for each socket. I can somehow understand the data loss while switching(if not properly handled) but I am not able to figure out why the data loss is occurring down the transfer after switching. I hope I am clear on what the issue is. I have also checked to send the data individually over each protocol without switching and there is no data loss.It I initially transfer the data over Ipv6 and then switch to  IPv4, there is no data loss. Also would really appreciate to know to how to investigate in this issue apart from using `errno` or `netstat`.

Comment: I suspect that you need to do a bit more explaining.  Are you dealing with the client or the server or both?  Surely, once a connection is established on a socket, it will either be an IPv4 or an IPv6 connection; you won't be able to switch to the other protocol without establishing a new socket connection, will you?

Comment: @user369823, Let me see if I understand, you establish *two* TCP sockets (`tcp` and `tcp6`) simultaneously between the client and server, then start data transfer over the `tcp` socket.  Somewhere in the middle,  you try to finish the aforementioned data transfer over the `tcp6` socket?  What could possibly be desirable about doing this?  If you are serious about switching sockets, why not close the `tcp` socket when you're ready to switch?

Comment: @Mike, Thanks for the reply- yes your are right. I have two connections already established in the main thread. the other thread based on some flags and condition switch the pointer used in the send function to IPv6 socket. The data is then transferred over IPv6 connection. I am not sure how will closing down the previous connection help . When I send the data over Ipv6 and then switch to Ipv4, there is no data loss. I am clueless as to why there is a data loss when I do the vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using TCP to send data you just can't loose a part of the information *in between*. You either receive the byte stream the way it was sent or receive nothing at all - provided that you are using the socket-related functions correctly.

There are several points you may want to investigate.

- First of all you must make sure that you are really sending the data which is lost. Add some logging on the server side application: dump anything that you transmit witn send() into some file. Include some extra info as well, like:

  Data packet no.==1234, *p_dataSocket.socket_id==11, Data=="data_contents_here", 22 bytes total; send() return==22

The important thing here is to watch the contents of `*p_dataSocket.socket_id`. Make sure that you are using mutex or something like that cause you have a thread which regularly reads `socket_id` contents and another thread which occasionally changes it. You are not guranteed against the getting of a wrong value from that address unless your threads have monopoly access to it while reading/writing. It is important both for normal program operation and for the debugging information generation.

Another possible problem here is the logic which selects `sentence` to send. Corruption of this variable may be hard to track in multithreaded program. The logging of transmitted information will help you here too.

- Use any TCP sniffer to check what TCP stack really transmits. Are there packets with lost data? If there are no those packets, try to find out which send() call was responsible for sending that data. If those packets exist, check the receiving side for bugs.
- `errno` value should not be used alone. Its value has meaning only when you get an erroneous return from a function. Try to find out when exactly errno becomes ESPIPE That may happen when any of API functions return something like `-1` (depends on function). When you find out where it happens you should find out what is wrong in that particular piece of code (debugger is your friend). Have in mind that `errno` behavior in multithreaded environment depends on your system implementation. Make sure that you use `-pthread` option (gcc) or at least compile with -D_REENTRANT to minimize the risks.
- Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866337/getting-illegal-seek-error-after-calling-accept) for some info about the possible cause of your situation with errno==ESPIPE. Try some debuggin techniques, as suggested there. Errno value of ESPIPE gives a hint that you are using file descriptors incorrectly somewhere in your program. Maybe somewhere you are using a socket *fd* as regular file or something like that. This may be caused by some race condition (simultaneous access to one object from several threads).

Comment: @Pavel-Thanks for all the suggestions.I am logging the data sent and socket ID sent which used against each send call. But I'll also log the amount of data sent after every send() call to it.I am also using mutex while changing the socket id in the other thread only. I would like to know if that should suffice?

Comment: I am also using the pthread option while compiling. For the error ESPIPE, I am not sure how to check the race condition but will get familiar with GDB. The program works fines though in reading and writing the data. I also did strace on my executable and it shows ESPIPE on lseek which is internally called while opening the file. I am m not able to find what can go wrong in that.

Comment: @user369823 No, using mutex in one thread only is not enough. In fact it is the same as not using mutex at all. Have in mind though that using syncronization primitives properly is _very important_, but bugs that arise from syncronization are usually unstable. I mean that if omitted mutex was the cause of problem, you would get an error sometimes, not everytime you switch. Anyway, try logging stuff and see what happens.

Comment: Thanx again for reply. I just checked for the ESPIPE error. It turns out and as you said perror is not supposed to be used if there is no error returned for any calls and set to something undefined/ not related. I checked by using strerror_r() instead and it returns success.

Comment: Secondly I see no error returned on receiving or sending the data. Seems to be problem with router dropping the packets as when I transfer data over IPv6 for a very short while and then switch to Ipv4, there is no data loss, but vice versa isnt happening. Also I tried sending data individually over each protocol. There is no data loss for Ipv4 but for Ipv6 I sometime get entire data and sometime not.. Need to do more debugging

Comment: If you are sure that every API function you use returns normally, you should just ignore `errno` value, at least for now. The fact that you have problems with using ipv6 alone (without switching) suggests that you have problems elsewhere. It may indeed be your router or you may even have some buggy ipv6 stack implementations on your machines. The best way to find out is to isolate your case further. It may be good idea to remove router away from picture by making a direct connection between machines. It may also help if you give some more information about data loss at ipv6-only connection.

Comment: I reduced the data buffer size for each recv call, and it works for Ipv6 as there is no fragmentation. I am certainly sure the kernel space for Ipv6 is too small and dropping packets. I am not able to chk that using netstat as multiple services are running on that server and I also do not have permissions to tcpdump to verify it. The other /proc/sys/.. files do not really indicate the loss clearly for Ipv6. Need to find out a way to choose correct buffer size for each protocol and also needs to be switched on the fly like the socket id. Would really appreciate for any suggestions.